# MS SQL - Inner Join on virtual Data making query slower to execute. why?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i want data from my table where i have specific condition to filter the data and i dont want to use where clause so i write virtual section and use inner join. but it makes query much slower.can anybody help me out to understand how inner join impacted on this query?

example is given below

--Slow query

```
SELECT * FROM myTable A
INNER JOIN 
(--virtual data
SELECT 1 CODE , 2 FkCode 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 CODE , 2 FkCode 
) B ON A.CODE = B.fkCode

--working fine
SELECT * FROM myTable A
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(--virtual data
SELECT 1 CODE , 2 FkCode 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 CODE , 2 FkCode 
) B ON A.CODE = B.fkCode
```

Comment: Have you checked execution plans?

Comment: yes inner join goes for clustered index seek(Cost 100%) and left outer join goes for clustered index scan(81 %) + merge join (19%).

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but what I would try is put the 'virtual data' in a temporary table, put a primary key on it. Might just help

Comment: yes sir i know this. i did the same way and it is working fine. i am expecting- what is that thing which is making slow, thank you.

Comment: You may have better luck asking on https://dba.stackexchange.com/. You should expand on your question though (on the other SE they'll ask as well), at least provide table structures, record numbers, execution plans, indices